# Why did Firebase CLI asked me if I wanted to use ESLint even when I selected TypeScript while initialising a cloud functions directory?

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

Here are the steps I did:

1. I installed the Firebase CLI using npm.
2. I created an empty directory
3. Then I run the command `firebase init functions` and chose one of my existing projects
4. Then the Firebase CLI asked me:  What language would you like to use to write Cloud Functions?
5. I chose TypeScript.
6. Then the CLI asked me: Do you want to use **ESLint** to catch probable bugs and enforce style? (Whereas ideally, it should ask me: Do you want to use **TSLint** to catch probable bugs and enforce style? as in this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DYfP-UIKxH0&t=289s)

Can someone help me with what could possibly go wrong here?

Comment: Show us your directory structure, and your eslint config maybe. You have no lintable files under `C:\Users\moksh\Desktop\cloud_functions\functions\src`

Comment: I have my index.ts file under C:\Users\moksh\Desktop\cloud_functions\functions\src

Comment: After the choosing TypeScript, it's asking:  Do you want to use ESLint to catch probable bugs and enforce style... (instead of TSLint)

Comment: The error message is telling you that you have no source code to compile at the location where the compiler is configured to look for it: "No files matching the pattern "'src/**/*'" were found".  I suggest editing the question to explain what you've done starting from the beginning.

Comment: @DougStevenson I follow this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DYfP-UIKxH0&t=289s. I run the firebase init functions command, then selected TypeScript. But after that Firebase CLI asked me Do you want to use ESLint whereas in the tutorial video it asked do you wan to use TSLint. I don't know why that happened.

Comment: Please **edit the question** to walk us through the details of everything you actually did to get to this point.  Don't depend on the contents of a video to explain the issue.  We should be able to duplicate the problem using the information you provide.

Comment: @DougStevenson Check now. I have edited the question as well as description

Comment: TSLint project has merged into ESLint. Now it’s deprecated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The video you're referring to is out of date.  The Firebase CLI was [recently updated](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/releases/tag/v8.11.0) to use ESLint instead of TSLint for checking possible code errors.  According to the release notes for CLI version 8.11.0:

> Replaces tslint with eslint as the default linter in new Cloud Functions for Firebase directories.

These tools both do similar things - check code for warnings.  Neither of these [lint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lint_(software)) tools affect the way the code actually work.  You can just take the default, and it won't matter much.

Comment: If you find an answer to be helpful, it's customary on Stack Overflow to accept the answer as correct by using the checkmark button to the left.